# file and line parameters with default values which can't be overridden

Tags: swift

I have this function:

```
func debug(_ value: Any, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    print(String(describing: value) + " at \(file):\(line)")
}
```

which this will print out the object passed in as `value`, and the file and line that the debug function was called from.

Is there any way in Swift of preventing the `file` and `line` parameters from being specified in code, but still have them print the correct values?

i.e. How can I prevent this from compiling?

```
debug("LIES", line: 1000000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Default values for the arguments are
the only mechanism to pass file and line number of the calling site to
the function, and can always be overwritten by providing those arguments explicitly.

Note that even if it were possible, the caller could still cheat with the `#sourceLocation` directive:

```
#sourceLocation(file: "nowhere", line: 10000)
debug(123) // 123 at nowhere:10000
```